# Non-updating inline CSS in PHP when trying to change background color of an HTML element imported from mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am a student(VERY new to PHP) trying to dynamically change the color of the background of each "fish" in a database, but before that, I need to try to change the background statically, however, I cannot even do that. I have tried using no quotes, quotes, and escape characters around the quotes to no avail.

**PHP/HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dinosaurs</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
  <?php
  include 'connection.php';
  $query = "SELECT Name FROM `fish` WHERE FishTypeID = 4";
  if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";
    echo "Error: Your query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    print("<div background-color = \"blue\">
            <h4>");
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      print($value . "
                <svg height = 64 width = 80>
                  <polygon points='1 31, 6 42, 1 47,26 63,60 50,80 64, 72 39, 80 16,60 28,26 17' />
                  <circle cx='20' cy='32' r='5' stroke='white' stroke-width='3' fill='black' />
                </svg>");
    }
    print("</h4></div>");
  }
    ?>
    <h1>dinosaurs</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: you are right when you say you need to do it without the database first, but this code is with the database components

Comment: @e4c5 I tried it with a String, but it didn't work.

Comment: is that why you made it more complicated by adding database related stuff?

Comment: I wish I didn't have to, but it is homework for my Computer App Dev class :/ The names and other stuff come in perfectly, they just don't update CSS.

Comment: well adding mysql code certainly isn't going to help you solve any CSS issues

Comment: I tried it without MySQL, but that didn't work, either. Any more thoughts @e4c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! It turns out that I was using an "=" instead of an ":" for my background-color assignment.